# Make numbers 1-31 with 1,9,7,8

Tags: formation-of-numbers

I am stuck with some of the solutions. These are rules:

- Use all four digits exactly once
- Allowed operations: +, -, x, ÷, ! (factorial), exponentiation, square root, squaring, parentheses

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found <strike>all</strike> <strike>almost all</strike> all of them (26 was fixed again):

> $1 = \sqrt{9}+7-8-1$
> $2 = \sqrt{9}+7-8*1$
> $3 = \sqrt{9}+7-8+1$
> $4 = \sqrt{9}+8-7*1$
> $5 = 8+7-9-1$
> $6 = 8+7-9*1$
> $7 = (1^8)^9*7$
> $8 = (1^7)^9*8$
> $9 = (1^7)^8*9$
> $10= 9+8-7*1$
> $11= 9+8-7+1$
> $12= 8+7-\sqrt{9}*1$
> $13= 8+7-\sqrt{9}+1$
> $14= 7*(9-8+1)$
> $15= (9-7)*8-1$
> $16= (9-7)*8*1$
> $17= (9-7)*8+1$
> $18= \sqrt{9}+8+7*1$
> $19= \sqrt{9}+8+7+1$
> $20= 7+8+\sqrt{9}!-1$
> $21= 7+8+\sqrt{9}!*1$
> $22= 7+8+\sqrt{9}!+1$
> $23= 7+8+9-1$
> $24= 7+8+9*1$
> $25= 7+8+9+1$
> $26= \sqrt{9}*(7-1)+8$
> $27= \sqrt{9}*(8!/7!+1)$
> $28= \sqrt{9}*7+8-1$
> $29= \sqrt{9}*7+8*1$
> $30= \sqrt{9}*7+8+1$
> $31= \sqrt{9}*8+7*1$
>
> I made pretty heavy use of $\sqrt{9}=3$, as well in certain cases of $1^x=1$ and $x!/(x-1)!=x$. Additionally, wherever I have a formula for $x$ with $-1$ at the end of the formula, $x+1$ and $x+2$ are easily obtained by using $*1$ and $+1$ respectively.

It should be noted that some expressions might not be in the simplest form. For some simply because I found the one listed earlier, for others (mainly 7, 8 and 9 - these can be done with simple addition and subtraction) because I liked this solution better.

Comment: shoudn't 2=(√3+7−8)∗1 (and similar usage) because without the brackets 8*1 comes before additions and soustractions ?

Comment: It indeed comes first, but it doesn't matter. Right now it's doing 3+7=10, 8*1=8, 10-8 is 2. Your version is doing 3+7=10, 10-8=2, 2*1=2. Basically, the *1 is a no-operation, and it doesn't matter where in the equation you insert a no-operation. I guess you could also say, it doesn't matter where in the equation you don't insert an operation.

Comment: brute force solver says 26 is impossible using only +, -, *, and /, so it's time to bring out the big guns.